# Android Tab colorizer

Tags: android, tabs

I develop a program to Android and it uses the new SlidingTabLayout view. The tab indicator color depends on the current app theme. I tried this:

```
    tabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return R.attr.colorAccent; // this is an int
        }
    });
```

The indicator color should use the *colorAccent*, but the app suddenly crashes, if I try to return any attribute value. That is not a solution if I write a concrete color instead of R.attr.colorAccent, because the indicator color changes dynamically.

Do you have any ideas?